# Move multiple documents into one enevelope

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have a user and a supervisor.
The user will submit some information, which will be used to generate a document, create an envelope and send it to the user to sign. I add 2 signing fields, one for the user and one for the supervisor.

What I would like to do is instead of sending it on to the supervisor after a user signs, I would like to get all the documents for each user and create a new envelope and send that one to the supervisor. This will then only have one email to the supervisor instead of no: users.

Is there a way this can be done? I have been unable to find a way to complete this.

Below is what I am doing at the current moment. For the first signer they are redirected.

```
const doc1 = new docusign.Document();
  doc1.documentBase64 = Buffer.from(htmlPage(args.htmlArgs)).toString('base64');
  doc1.name = args.documentName;
  doc1.fileExtension = 'html';
  doc1.documentId = '1';

  env.documents = [doc1];

  const signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: args.htmlArgs.submitterEmail,
    name: args.htmlArgs.submitterName,
    clientUserId: 1,
    recipientId: 1,
    routingOrder: 1 });

  // Signer 2 is the supervisor. Gets sent the document after signer 1 signs
  const signer2 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: args.htmlArgs.supervisorEmail,
    name: args.htmlArgs.supervisorName,
    recipientId: 2,
    routingOrder: 2 });

  const signHere1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    anchorString: '**signature_1**',
    anchorYOffset: '10', anchorUnits: 'pixels',
    anchorXOffset: '20'});

  const signHere2 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    anchorString: '**signature_2**',
    anchorYOffset: '10', anchorUnits: 'pixels',
    anchorXOffset: '20'});

  // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
  signer1.tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    signHereTabs: [signHere1]});

  signer2.tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    signHereTabs: [signHere2]});

  env.recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
    signers: [signer1, signer2],
  });
  env.status = args.status;
```

Comment: Please confirm (or edit your question to make this more clear). You want one envelope that goes to multiple users AND then to the supervisor? (That can be done with document visibility.)

Comment: Each user will generate there own envelope. However, instead of then sending each envelope onto the supervisor, i want to combine all the envelopes into one to send to the supervisor

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.
There are multiple things to consider here:

1. RoutingOrder - you can use that to have users sign in the order you choose and the suprevisor last.
2. Document Visibly feature enables you to prevent user 1 from seeing user 2 documents if that's what you want.
3. Merge fields. the ability to get data into a document.
4. Using a template to nicely capture the repeatable process for all the above.

Would suggest to first do all of this without the API using the web app to understand the capabilities. If you can do it via web app - you can use the API to do the same. So that's a good way to know what can or cannot be done.